# js: str.replace() with Promise

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, promise, es6-promise

I want to asynchronously replace a part of the string

```js
var str = "abc"
var str2 = str.replace(/a/g,m=>{
  new Promise(r=>r("x"),j=>j("rejected"))
      .then(result=>result)

})

console.log(str2)
```

I tried using async/await:

```js
var str = "abc"
var str2 = str.replace(/a/g, async(m)=>{
  return await new Promise(r=>r("x"),j=>j("rejected"))
      .then(result=>result)

})

console.log(str2) //[object Promise]bc
```

Comment: Will each replacement replace the same thing? Eg if `a` is replaced, it'll always be replaced with the same replacement character/substring?

Comment: No, the real process is to replace base64 encoded data with it's src link after uploading to the cloud.

Comment: So if the same base64 data is found twice, you'll construct *two separate links* for it, are you sure? That sounds pretty odd

Comment: `new Promise(r=>r("x"),j=>j("rejected"))` I really think you need a refresher course in how Promises are created

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm pretty sure that part is just there for a minimal example of "I have a Promise here, how do I consume it and replace properly?"

Comment: Do you need the process to be completed after some event or you just want to shift the normal execution to event queue??

Comment: *I want to asynchronously replace a part of the string* - why? - besides the fact that replace callback doesn't support that, so **nothing** you can do to make it work, why would you WANT that?

Comment: @CertainPerformance - I really think the OP is clueless about the Promise constructor

Comment: I want to perform an uploading process to the cloud to obtain the link, then replace base64; part of the string with it's link.

Comment: The `Promise` doesn't use the match (hence the example doesn't make much sense). So just get the value and replace it in `.then()`.

Comment: @Sheldeeb it's better you update your question with a real/complete problem rather asking about you think the solution can be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript : Async/await in .replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33631041/javascript-async-await-in-replace)

Comment: I find it strange that you'd need to do this async, string edditing is so immensely fast that I doubt it's necessary. anyway. I googled somewhat and I figured this could probably help you: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/async-await-javascript-5038668ec6eb It's a guide to promises since Async-Await are extentions of promises.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `.replace` callback, you can construct an array of Promises from the matched substrings, *and then ignore the return value from `.replace`*. From the array of Promises, call `Promise.all` on it to get an array of replacements. Then, call `.replace` *again* with the same pattern, and use the replacer function to replace each matched substring with the top item in the replacement array:

```js
// Replace the below function with the code required for your actual API call
const getReplacement = str => Promise.resolve(`[${str}]`);

const promises = [];
var str = "abcabcb"
str.replace(/[ab]/g, m => {
  promises.push(getReplacement(m));
});
Promise.all(promises)
  .then((results) => {
    const output = str.replace(/[ab]/g, () => results.shift());
    console.log(output);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // handle errors
  });
```

Comment: just because OP wants the `fish to fly`? :D

Comment: this will run getReplacement(m) immediately

Comment: @Sheldeeb No, `getReplacement` is asynchronous - see how it returns a Promise? You can replace it with anything else asynchronous (like the actual logic for your network request) and the overall logic will still work fine.

Comment: (1) You're not using the same regular expression in the first `.replace` as in the second. The first RE is `/-/`, which matches `-` in `a-b`, but the second RE is `/'-'/`, but there are no `'`s, so no matches occur. (2) Since the replacement is asynchronous, you must put everything inside the `Promise.all`'s `.then` call

Answer (score -3):

**Remove the then part it will return resolve or reject value**

```
var str = "abc"
var str2 = str.replace(/a/g, async(m)=>{
  return await new Promise((r,j)=>r("x"))
})
```

Comment: `if(dynamicResult){` when the condition will be `falsy`?

Comment: i just gave example, let me re write

Comment: it will always be a promise object no matter in what stage it will never be falsy.

Comment: no it is not going to be promise object. it will be resolve or reject value

Comment: async - await only return the resolved value. so we do not get promise object.

Comment: will return: [object Promise]bc